# SPI driver on the FRDM-K64F and continuous clock

Tags: embedded, driver, spi, bare-metal, cortex-m

I'm trying to create my own SPI bare-metal driver on the FRDM-K64F board. I only wrote a initialisation function for now.

In order to test the functional I set the continuous clock register. I expected that the continuous clock would *always* generate a clock even when no data was set on the bus. However I'm not seeing a clock on my oscilloscope.

Why am I not seeing a clock on my oscilloscope? Am I misinterpreting the continuous clock register? Or did I forget to implement another register?

```
int frdm_spi_init(SPI_Type *spi, struct frdm_spi_mode *mode, uint32_t hz) 
{

        if(mode->frame < FRDM_SPI_MIN_FRAME_SIZE) {
          return -1;
        }

        // Enable clock
        SIM_SCGC6 |= SIM_SCGC6_SPI0(FRDM_ENABLE);

        // For debug purpose
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_CONT_SCKE_MASK;
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) |= (FRDM_ENABLE<<SPI_MCR_CLR_RXF_SHIFT);

        // Master/slave
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_MSTR_MASK;
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) |= (mode->mode<<SPI_MCR_MSTR_SHIFT);

        if(mode->mode == FRDM_SPI_MASTER)  {

          //Frame size
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_FMSZ_MASK;
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= (((mode->frame-1) & 0x0F)<<SPI_CTAR_FMSZ_SHIFT);

          // Spi mode
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_CPOL_MASK;
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= (mode->CPOL)<<SPI_CTAR_CPOL_SHIFT;
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_CPHA_MASK;
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= (mode->CPHA)<<SPI_CTAR_CPHA_SHIFT;

          //Always in msb mode
          SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_LSBFE_MASK;

        } else if(mode->mode == FRDM_SPI_SLAVE) {

          /*TODO*/
        }

        //frequency
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_ASC_MASK;
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 1<<SPI_CTAR_ASC_SHIFT;
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_PASC_MASK;
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 0<<SPI_CTAR_PASC_SHIFT;
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_DBR_MASK;
        SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 0<<SPI_CTAR_DBR_SHIFT;

        // Fifo
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_DIS_TXF_MASK;
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) != 0<<SPI_MCR_DIS_TXF_SHIFT;

        //Enable
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_MDIS_MASK;
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) != 0<<SPI_MCR_MDIS_SHIFT;

        // Start hardware
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_HALT_MASK;
        SPI_MCR_REG(spi) |= 0<<SPI_MCR_HALT_SHIFT;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are a chip designer, you don't "implement" special function registers.  Rather, as a programmer you configure them or assign them values in order to implement functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code presented does not configure the pin-control registers for the SPI; this may be done elsewhere, but you should verify that the pin configuration is correct and the SCK for the SPI port you are using is MUX'ed to the pin you are expecting.  It would probably be better to set the pin configuration in this function in any case.

Also this block looks suspicious:

```
    //frequency
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_ASC_MASK;
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 1<<SPI_CTAR_ASC_SHIFT;
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_PASC_MASK;
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 0<<SPI_CTAR_PASC_SHIFT;
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) &= ~SPI_CTAR_DBR_MASK;
    SPI_CTAR_REG(spi,0) |= 0<<SPI_CTAR_DBR_SHIFT;
```

It does not use the `hz` parameter, and `Y |= 0 << X` will always be equal to `Y`.  It leaves ASC = 1, PASC = 0, DBR = 0, only the last of these affects the clock frequency. You have not set BR and PBR:

> SCK baud rate = (f<sub>P</sub> /PBR) x [(1+DBR)/BR]

Assuming the current values are at the reset state, that would give a clock of f<sub>P</sub>/4.

Furthermore you have a typo in:

```
    //Enable
    SPI_MCR_REG(spi) &= ~SPI_MCR_MDIS_MASK;
    SPI_MCR_REG(spi) != 0<<SPI_MCR_MDIS_SHIFT;   
                 //  ^ 
                 //  error |= not !=
```

However the second line does nothing even when corrected, but the first line already clears the bit, and OR'ing in zero does nothing (still), so the error is benign. I am surprised however that your compiler did not issue a "statement does nothing" warning.

I believe that there are macros for setting the peripheral register fields individually such as `SPI_CTAR_ASC(x)`, `SPI_CTAR_PASC(x)` etc.  You  should probably use these for clarity and to avoid masking errors and maintenance nightmares.